# C# ReadProcessMemory или WriteProcessMemory был выполнен только частично

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь убивать процессы по местоположению, получается не очень...

```
Необработанное исключение: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 
Запрос ReadProcessMemory или WriteProcessMemory был выполнен только частично. 

в System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId, Boolean firstModuleOnly)
в System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetFirstModuleInfo(Int32 processId)
в System.Diagnostics.Process.get_MainModule()
```

До этого ещё отдавало ошибку: `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Отказано в доступе`, решилось правами администратора.
Но иногда всё равно всплывает.

Сам метод:

```
    public static void KillProcesses(string path)
    {
        foreach (var pr in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
        {
            if (path == pr.MainModule.FileName)
            {
                    pr.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
```

Больше всего интересует именно первая ошибка, с чем это может быть связано? Если делать это всё через `try-catch`, софт вылетать конечно перестанет, но вот процессы убиваться тоже не будут.

Answer (score 0):

Да, у меня аналогичная проблема проявилась на одном из нескольких сотен компьютеров: прислали пачку файлов логов ошибок и среди них это и обнаружилось в одном файле.
Первая мысль была, что это что-то аппаратно-драйверное: и возникает редко, и проблемы с чтением памяти.

```
Process[] processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName( "Informer" );
for ( int i=0; i< processes.Length; i++ )
{
   string runningProcessFilename = processes[ i ].MainModule.FileName;
}
```

Процессы в моем случае могут быть запущены под сессиями других пользователей, получение данных по запущенным процессам происходит из сессии с правами администратора.

Answer (score -1):

Перемещение в папку файла .exe перед запуском процесса Process.Start() помогло.

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = pathToFolderWithYourProcessExe
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык 2. [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)